# Sorting a vector with 2 pairs inside

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, std-pair

Well, I have a vector, pair >, and I'm wondering how he does the sort? with sort(v.begin(),v.end());

```
using namespace std;

int main(){
   int n; cin >> n;
   vector<pair<pair<int,int>, pair<int,int>>> v;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      long long x1,y1,x2,y2;
      cin>>x1>>y1>>x2>>y2;
      v.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(x1,y1),make_pair(x2,y2)));
   }   
   sort(v.begin(),v.end());
   for(auto& p : v){
      cout<<p.first.first<<" "<<p.first.second<<" "<<p.second.first<<" "<<p.second.second<<"\n";
  }
   return 0;
}
```

input:

```
4   
5 19 8 17
5 15 15 5
0 20 20 0
8 10 10 8
```

output:

```
0 20 20 0
5 15 15 5
5 19 8 17
8 10 10 8
```

Comment: Sorts left to right:  first x1, the if tied y1, then if tied x2, then if tied y2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the class `std::pair` there is defined operator

```
template<class T1, class T2>
constexpr bool operator< (const pair<T1, T2>&, const pair<T1, T2>&);
```

that acts the following way

> Returns: x.first < y.first || (!(y.first < x.first) && x.second <
>   y.second).

So for example for two pairs of the type `std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int>>`

```
{ { 5, 19 }, { 8, 17 } }
  ^^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
{ { 5, 15 }, { 15, 5 } }
  ^^^^^^^^^
```

at first the pairs `{ 5, 19 }` and `{ 5, 15 }` are compared using the same `operator <`.

As the second pair is less than the first pair then the second pair will precede the first pair in the result vector.

If they (first pairs) were equal each other as for example

```
{ { 5, 15 }, { 8, 17 } }
  ^^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
{ { 5, 15 }, { 15, 5 } }
  ^^^^^^^^^
```

then the second pairs were compared. Because the pair `{ 8, 17 }` is less then `{ 15, 5 }` then the first pair is less than the second pair.

The pairs `{ 8, 17 }` and `{ 15, 5 }` are compared using the same template `operator <`.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) defines a [`operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) if the contained types support comparison via `operator<`, and you're using `int`, so it is provided by default.

`std::sort` uses this `operator<` to sort the elements [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

If you were using an arbitrary type without `operator<` defined, you would have to provide your own comparator to `std::sort`